# What must be the flux on sides BC and AB at given position?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics

[image]

Many people says that the whole flux is zero at given position but how could this is possible as sides AB and CD is perpendicular to flux and side BC is parallel .

Comment: Review the definition of flux.  Flux is not defined on the boundary of plane figures.

Comment: Why is this so please always explain or give reference for what you say

Comment: What do *you* say and why?

Comment: Your question does not make sense. Are you talking about flux or curl? Flux is defined for surfaces (not for lines) whereas curl is defined for lines.

Comment: You are confused.   Step back, review the original problem and start over.  Questions that involve wires don't normally need the concept of flux.  And as @YashasSamaga points out, flux is defined on surfaces, not lines.

Answer (score 1):

Your plane is completely parallel to the flux lines. Flux is zero because none of the flux lines penetrate through the two-dimensional surface of your plane. Lines AB and CD are not two-dimensional, they're just single-dimensional plane boundaries which of course flux cannot interact with. In order to gain flux, your plane has to be in any way perpendicular to the flux lines.

Answer (score -1):

Flux definition:
$$\Phi=\iint \vec{E}.d\vec{A}=\iint E.cos<E,dA>.dA$$
where $<E,dA>$ is the angle between $\vec{E}$ and $d\vec{A}$. For a surface, the direction is its normal, which always normal to the surface. For your case, evidently, $<E,dA>=\frac{\pi}{2}$, so $\Phi=0$.

Comment: This is the correct definition of flux, but there is a step missing in applying it to the OP:  *What exactly is $\mathrm{d}A$?"   In fact, there is no $\mathrm{d}A$ in this problem.

Comment: Does ABCD not form a surface?

Comment: As far as I can tell the OP is trying to calculate the flux across line AB.

Comment: the flux across line AB? Can you see anything about $line$ in the definition of flux?

Comment: That's the point:  the OP is trying to calculate flux across a line.  Read the original post again.